# Using PHP curl to store object with open stack API file storage

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, openstack

I am using php curl to call open stack's api to store a object. My curl call looks like this

```
 $token = $this->getToken();       
 $url = 'http://myfilestorageurl.com/v1/AUTH_volume/container/dummyfile.pdf';
```

dummyfile.pdf is the file name i want the stored file to be called.

```
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Auth-Token:'.$token,
        'Content-Length: 5611',      //not sure if its required
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT',   //not sure if its required
        'Content-Location:/data/dummyfile.pdf'
    ));


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_call);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");     
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The response keeps returning a 408 Request Timeout

Has anyone figured this out. Also am i specifying the file location to be uploaded correctly using the content-location header or is there another way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Anyone whos having the same issue i solved the problem the following way:

```
 $url = 'http://myurltouploadfileto.com';
 $fp = fopen('http://urlToFileToUpload.com');
 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Auth-Token:sometoken'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);     //this was the main one that i was missing
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```

This seemed to resolve it and upload the file from the url to object storage server.